# Pascal print numbers alternately

Tags: pascal

I have a task to print each number from the input alternately, firstly numbers with even indexes, then numbers with odd indexes. I have solved it, but only for one line of numbers, but I have to read n lines of numbers.

Expected input:

```
2

3 5 7 2

4 2 1 4 3
```

Expected output:

```
7 5 2

1 3 2 4
```

Where 2 is number of lines, 3 and 4 are numbers of numbers, 5, 7, 2 and 2, 1 , 4, 3 are these numbers.

```
Program numbers;
Uses crt;

var k,n,x,i,j: integer;
var tab : Array[1..1000] of integer;
var tab1 : Array[1..1000] of integer;
var tab2 : Array[1..1000] of integer;

begin
    clrscr;
    readln(k);
    
    for i:=1 to k do
    begin
    read(n);
        for j:=1 to n do
        begin
            read(tab[j]);
            if(j mod 2 = 0) then
            tab1[j]:=tab[j]
            else 
            begin
            tab2[j]:=tab[j];
            end;
        end;
    end;
    
    for j:=1 to n do
    if tab1[j]<>0 then write(tab1[j], ' ');
    for j:=1 to n do
    if tab2[j]<>0 then write(tab2[j], ' ');
         
end.
```

Comment: You can actually _mix_ your input routines and output routines. Try to `read` and `write` in the _same_ loop. From your description the task does not require to actually store the values into an `array`.
By the way `j mod 2 = 0` is equivalent to `not odd(j)`. It’s for my taste also less “cryptic”.

Comment: Proper use of code formatting (indentation, whitespace around operators, etc.) will also make your code much easier to read and reason about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's clean up the formatting, and use a record to keep track of each "line" of input.

```pascal
program numbers;
uses
  crt;

type
  TLine = record
    count : integer;
    numbers : array[1..1000] of integer
  end;

var
  numLines, i, j : integer;
  lines : Array[1..1000] of TLine;

begin
  clrscr;
  readln(numLines);

  for i := 1 to numLines do
  begin
    read(lines[i].count);

    for j := 1 to lines[i].count do
      read(lines[i].numbers[j])
  end

end.
```

We can read each line in. Now, how do we print the odd and even indices together? Well, we *could* do math on each index, *or* we could just increment by `2` instead of `1` using a while loop.

```
program numbers;
uses
  crt;

type
  TLine = record
    count : integer;
    numbers : array[1..1000] of integer
  end;

var
  numLines, i, j : integer;
  lines : Array[1..1000] of TLine;

begin
  clrscr;
  readln(numLines);

  // Read in lines.

  for i := 1 to numLines do
  begin
    read(lines[i].count);

    for j := 1 to lines[i].count do
      read(lines[i].numbers[j])
  end;

  // Print out lines.

  for i := 1 to numLines do
  begin
    j := 1;

    while j <= lines[i].count do
    begin
      write(lines[i].numbers[j], ' ');
      j := j + 2
    end;

    j := 2;

    while j <= lines[i].count do
    begin
      write(lines[i].numbers[j], ' ');
      j := j + 2
    end;

    writeln
  end
end.
```

Now if we run this:

```
2
3 4 5 6
4 6 2 4 1
4 6 5
6 4 2 1
```

One thing we can note is that the following loop is the same for both odd and even indexes, except for the start index.

```
    while j <= lines[i].count do
    begin
      write(lines[i].numbers[j], ' ');
      j := j + 2
    end;
```

This is a perfect place to use a procedure. Let's call it `PrintEveryOther` and have it take an index to start from and a line to print.

```
program numbers;
uses
  crt;

type
  TLine = record
    count : integer;
    numbers : array[1..1000] of integer
  end;

var
  numLines, i, j : integer;
  lines : Array[1..1000] of TLine;
  
  procedure PrintEveryOther(start : integer; line :TLine);
  var
    i : integer;

  begin
    i := start;

    while i <= line.count do
    begin
      write(line.numbers[i], ' ');
      i := i + 2
    end

  end;
  
begin
  clrscr;
  readln(numLines);

  for i := 1 to numLines do
  begin
    read(lines[i].count);

    for j := 1 to lines[i].count do
      read(lines[i].numbers[j])
  end;

  for i := 1 to numLines do
  begin
    PrintEveryOther(1, lines[i]);
    PrintEveryOther(2, lines[i]);
    writeln
  end
  
end.
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! You are great.